# Lipschitz constant for $f(x,y)=e^x \sin y$

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

> Calculate Lipschitz constant for
>   $$f(x,y)=e^x \sin y$$
>   on $R=\{|x|\leq 1, |y|\leq 2\pi\}$

---

My finally answer is $L=e=2.718$

$L$ is Lipschitz constant

Because

$|f(x,y_2)-f(x,y_1)|=|e^x(\sin y_2-\sin y_1)|$

$=|e^x|.|\sin y_2-\sin y_1|$

$\leq |e^x| |y_2-y_1|$

Because [$|\sin a - \sin b| \leq |a-b|$]

Is the last inequality true ?

$|f(x,y_2)-f(x,y_1)|\leq |e^1||y_2-y_1|$

Then $L=e$

True?

Comment: You want to find $L \geq 0$ such that $\forall (x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2) \in R$, $\|f(x_1,y_1) - f(x_2,y_2)\| \leq L\|(x_1,y_1) - (x_2,y_2)\|$ so you can't fix the first variable. The inequality with the sinus is true for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. 
Please correct your first equality $e = 2,718$.

Comment: lipshtize $\rightarrow$ lipschitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, but another way to do this is to notice that the function $f(x,y)$ is smooth. So with that, we can simply maximize the gradient of $f(x,y)$ over the domain you want and this will be our Lipschitz constant.